# Acceso directo a la carpeta de bootstrap en node_modules

Tags: bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

Estoy migrando un proyecto del trabajo de bootstrap v4 a v5 y en la nueva version se implementa el uso de variables sass y esto ayuda un monton, el punto es que quisiera saber de que manera puedo mejorar estas rutas en mi archivo de styles.scss.

```
@import "../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
@import "../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

La ruta donde el compilador va a buscar el style.scss es esta:

[image: Ruta de style.scss]

Entonces quisiera saber como puedo acceder al root directamente del host para ahorrarme todas esas "../" en css es las rutas son tan simple como "/node_modules/..." pero claro, en sass la situacion cambia.
No estoy utilizando nada webpack ni nada, es un proyecto hecho con php al que simplemente le acabo de hacer npm install bootstrap@5.3.3

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.